# сравнение с шаблоном, хранящимся в таблице

Tags: mysql

как в *mysql* сравнить строку с шаблоном, хранящимся в ячейке таблицы?

например:

```
> select * from t;
+-------+---+
|   p   | d |
+-------+---+
| bla%  | 1 |
| b%bum | 2 |
+-------+---+
```

каким запросом можно (если, конечно, возможно), подставив в него `blabla`, получить `1`, а подставив `bahbum`, получить `2`?

типа:

```
> select d from t where ..... 'blabla';
+---+
| d |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
> select d from t where ..... 'bahbum';
+---+
| d |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
```

p.s. сам тип шаблона не принципиален. можно и, например, regex-овый `bla.*` вместо `bla%`, если так проще/короче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE 'blabla' LIKE t.p;
```

Comment: спасибо! хоть я уже и сам догадался, что можно было поменять местами аргументы оператора like. так оно обычно и бывает: ничего не придумывается, пока не задашь свой вопрос кому-нибудь другому.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Только учти, что такой запрос - это фуллскан таблицы. Так что если вдруг производительность критична, то это будет весьма плохим решением...

Comment: стоит добавить это в ответ.